# "GRANT ALL TO role" in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Please can someone explain what the following statement does in SQL Server 2005:

```
GRANT ALL TO pax_writer
```

pax_writer is a database role previously created using the statement

```
CREATE ROLE pax_writer AUTHORIZATION dbo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Grants database permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178569(SQL.90).aspx)

This is the only time you can leave the `ON ThingsAndStuff` clause out.

> ALL
>
> This option does not grant all
>   possible permissions. Granting ALL is
>   equivalent to granting the following
>   permissions: BACKUP DATABASE, BACKUP
>   LOG, CREATE DATABASE, CREATE DEFAULT,
>   CREATE FUNCTION, CREATE PROCEDURE,
>   CREATE RULE, CREATE TABLE, and CREATE
>   VIEW.

Answer (score 4):

GRANT ALL TO "someone" grants all permissions for all objects available in the database. But I'm not sure this is suppose to work in sql server 2005 as far as I'm concerned they left "GRANT ALL" only for backward compatibility.

According to the article in sql server 2005 works like this:

1. If the securable is a database,
   "ALL" means BACKUP DATABASE, BACKUP
   LOG, CREATE DATABASE, CREATE
   DEFAULT, CREATE FUNCTION, CREATE
   PROCEDURE, CREATE RULE, CREATE
   TABLE, and CREATE VIEW.
2. If the securable is a scalar
   function, "ALL" means EXECUTE and
   REFERENCES.
3. If the securable is a table-valued
   function, "ALL" means DELETE,
   INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT, and
   UPDATE.
4. If the securable is a stored
       procedure, "ALL" means EXECUTE.
5. If the securable is a table, "ALL"
   means DELETE, INSERT, REFERENCES,
   SELECT, and UPDATE.
6. If the securable is a view, "ALL" means DELETE, INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT, and UPDATE.

Hopefully someone will the right answer

[MSDN - GRANT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx)

Comment: Are you sure? The MSDN documentation explicitly says, "It does not grant all possible permissions".

Comment: in the article i has how it works.. but in earlier verionse of sql server might have being like i said. Unfortunately I'm not sure.

Comment: i think it'd be a good idea not to use GRANT ALL, the reason the change it i think it was beacause in sql server 2005 the add additional permissions at various scopes that can be used to manage user permissions...