# Why was execute permission denied using GRANT ALL?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I just did this:

```
sqlcmd -E -S .\SQL_EXPRESS

USE master;
GO

CREATE LOGIN [BUILTIN\Users] FROM WINDOWS;
GO

USE PMInfrastructure;
GO

CREATE USER [BUILTIN\Users] FROM LOGIN [BUILTIN\Users];
GO

CREATE ROLE rCetrus;
GO

ALTER ROLE rCetrus ADD MEMBER [BUILTIN\Users];
GO

GRANT ALL TO rCetrus
GO
```

and then ran some code and got this:

```
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'InstallInfo_GetLatest', database 'PMInfrastructure', schema 'dbo'.
```

I thought GRANT ALL granted everything ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["GRANT ALL TO role" in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338445/grant-all-to-role-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the documentation:

> Arguments ALL This option is deprecated and maintained only for
>   backward compatibility. It does not grant all possible permissions.
>   Granting ALL is equivalent to granting the following permissions.

[More information here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx)